# Keras Error: Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 2 arrays

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, keras

Hello I need assistance on building my Unet. I keep on getting the Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 2 arrays.

My Input_shape = (2, 256, 256, 120, 1) which is the same size as my mask.

I am using Keras DataGenerator.

```
def __data_generation(self, list_IDs_temp):
        X = np.empty([self.batch_size,self.n_channels, *self.dim])
        Y = np.empty([self.batch_size, 3 ,*self.dim])
        X_ = []
        y_ = []

        # Generate data
        for i, ID in enumerate(list_IDs_temp):
            img = nib.load(im_path + ID).get_data() 
            mask = nib.load(label_path + ID).get_data() 
            mask = np.clip(mask, 0, 255)
            cmask = (mask * 1. / 255)
            out = cmask 
            X_.append(img)
            y_.append(out)
        X = np.expand_dims(X_, -1)
        y = np.expand_dims(y_, -1)
        # y = np.concatenate((1 - y, y), -1)
        X = np.array(X)
        y = np.array(y)

        print ('### Dataset loaded')
        print ('\t{}'.format(im_path))
        print ('\t{}\t{}'.format(X.shape, y.shape))
        print ('\tX:{:.1f}-{:.1f}\ty:{:.1f}-{:.1f}\n'.format(X.min(), X.max(), y.min(), y.max()))
        return X, y
```

My Training code:

```
X, y = DataGenerator(partition['train'], **params) 

model = build_model() 
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-4), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['binary_accuracy'])

checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint('model.{epoch:03d}.hdf5', save_freq=5)

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=2, epochs=1, callbacks=[checkpointer], validation_split=0.2)
```

Comment: The shape 

> (2, 256, 256, 120, 1).

Where does 120 come from?

Comment: @TimbusCalin it is the depth of the image. its a medical image (256,256,120) original shape

Comment: Please assist I have been struggling for days now @TimbusCalin. when I use fit_generator the program runs and consume all the memory. and the Total params: 1,022,609

Comment: So you have 3 classes( in your Y). Normally if you have, say 30 classes , the shape of Y should be (batch_size, height, width, number_of_classes(30), channels)

Comment: So the Y_shape should be (32, 256, 256, 30) or (32,30,256,256), presuming that you have binary(grayscale) masks, where 32 == batch_size and 30 = number_of_classes.

Comment: how do I resize this all I have just been struggling. input size (256,256,120). Because it is a 3D Unet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202271/discussion-between-timbus-calin-and-user3551487).